# netcore: manually create a Logger without using LoggerFactory

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm creating a console logger using:

```
_log = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole().CreateLogger(this.GetType().Name);
```

Now I'm getting the following warning:

```
controllers\DummyController.cs(31,20): warning CS0618:
'ConsoleLoggerExtensions.AddConsole(ILoggerFactory)' is obsolete: 
'This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The 
recommended alternative is AddConsole(this ILoggingBuilder builder).'
```

I'm not in the context of a dependency injection container.

UPDATE:
I also tried using DI like this:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
var log = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>();
log.LogInformation("testing _log");
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error Message:                                                                                                                                                
  System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.                                                                                                         
Parameter name: logger                                                                                                                                        
Stack Trace:                                                                                                                                                  
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)                                                                                                                                                             
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogInformation(ILogger logger, String message, Object[] args)
```

It seems I can't get the logger from the container

Comment: You can probably do it via reflection or something else.  It might be overkill, but what I've done in certain scenarios where performance is not a major concern is to just create my `ServiceCollection` and `ServiceProvider` and just use the extension methods provided.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried with DI but it seems like there's something missing. I updated my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're creating a Dependency Injection container, you can use the following code to instantiate a logger instance from the logger factory.

```
var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
var logger = loggerFactory.Create("mylogger");
logger.LogInformation("Hello {0}", "world");
```

Or, you can create it via the typed interface

```
var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyType>>();
logger.LogInformation("Hello {0}", "world");
```

However, you are **not** able to do the following:

```
var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
```

As the non-generic interface is not registered in the Dependency Injection container, the reasoning for this is that the logging libraries infer the logger name from the generic type, and when you use `ILogger` only, there's nothing to derive a name from, versus `MyProject.MyNamespace.MyType`.

Slightly off topic, but using the extension method `GetRequiredService<T>` instead of `GetService<T>` would at least help you avoid a possible `NullReferenceException`, and have the application fail earlier.

Answer (score 14):

The interface has changed, so that you use a static Create() factory method on LoggerFactory, with a delegate that is passed in a configuration object that you configure the provider on. The factory can then be used to create loggers as before:

```
    ILogger<Program> logger = LoggerFactory
        .Create(logging => logging.AddConsole())
        .CreateLogger<Program>();
    logger.LogInformation("Hello World!");
```

While an application should usually use a host builder, this can be very useful in unit testing, as you can pass in a real logger that writes to the console (instead of a mock), and see the output in your test results.

This is taken from the simple walkthough example at: https://github.com/sgryphon/essential-logging/tree/master/examples/GettingStarted

There is also further examples that show how to configure via a host builder, and how to use the Microsoft high performance logging pattern.